# Is there a king or queen of Equestria?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

Typically, princes and princesses are the children of the king and queen. So far, we have seen princes and princesses in Equestria (Celestia, Luna, Blueblood, Cadence, Shining Armor) and saw flashbacks of King Sombra in the Crystal Empire.

Based on the [Magical Mystery Cure](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Mystery_Cure) episode, we see that

> princes and princesses are not necessarily inherited titles.

Even in current times, at least *some* kingdoms have kings and queens (evident from the existence of Queen Chrysalis). Is there a king or queen of Equestria, or has there been?

Comment: So possibly Equestria is a principality and not a kingdom or duchy or county.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  [According to Lauren Faust](http://comments.deviantart.com/4/1603670/1791456540), creator of *Friendship is Magic*, Celestia was only given the title of "Princess" because "Queen" (her original title) had been given an "evil" connotation by Disney movies.  In particular:

> That's what happened. I was told that because of Disney movies, girls assume that Queens are evil (although I only remember 1 evil queen) and Princesses are good. I was also told that the perceived youth of a Princess is preferable to consumers.
>
> **She does not have parents that outrank her.** I brought the weirdness of that situation to my bosses, but it did not seem to be a continuity concern to them, so I'm letting it alone. **I always wanted her to be the highest authority, and so she remains so.** And I certainly don't want marriage to be what would escalate her. (Bad messages to girls and what not.)